# Найти количество счастливых билетов

Tags: python, c++, комбинаторика, перебор, арифметика

Даны 2 восьмизначные числа:
N и M.
К примеру:
1000 0000 и 9999 9999
надо написать код, который будет проверять, **равность сумм** первых и последних четырех цифр в диапазоне от N до M.

к примеру: 1234 9001 сумма первой половины 1+2+3+4=10, второй половины 9+0+0+1=10.

Надо в конце вывести сколько всего чисел подходят по этому критерию.

написала код на с++, но работает он 3.3 секунды, мне надо что бы он работал меньше секунды

Comment: 3.3 секунды? А сколько чисел то за это время обрабатывает?

Comment: от 1000 0000 до 9999 9999

Comment: а, это и есть диапазоны

Comment: хотелось бы увидеть код

Comment: я оставила ссылку на изображение с кодом

Comment: можете объяснить хотя бы одну причину, почему вы привели код картинкой на стороннем ресурсе, вместо того, чтобы привести его прямо в вопросе текстом?

Comment: я тут впервые, извиняюсь

Comment: сдесь принять весь код и ошибки приводить текстом, отредактируйте, пожалуйста вопрос

Comment: я изменила, как вы просили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте предвычислить для четырехзначных чисел суммы:

```
int lucky(int M, int N)
{
    int s[10000] = {0}, total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9999; ++i)
    {
        for(int k = i; k; k/=10)
        {
            s[i] += k%10;
        }
    }
    for(int i = M; i <= N; ++i)
        if (s[i/10000] == s[i%10000]) ++total;
    return total;
}
```

Ваша программа работает на моей машине 1.13±0.03с, моя - 0.16±0.03с.

Для CrazyElf: а вот *микро*оптимизация, снижающая время с 1.16 до 1.15 - немного быстрее просчитать таблицу:

```
int lucky(int M, int N)
{
    int s[10000] = {0}, total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 999; ++i)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int k = i; k; k/=10)
        {
            sum += k%10;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            s[10*i+j] = sum+j;
    }
    for(int i = M; i <= N; ++i)
        if (s[i/10000] == s[i%10000]) ++total;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Отлично вообще!

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, но если применить немного математики, то можно и быстрее :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, очень благодарна.

Comment: @Harry Я тут пытался на питоне микрооптимизировать процесс, но супротив такого куда уже )

Comment: @CrazyElf Как правило, лучшая оптимизация - смена алгоритма :)

Comment: Намек поняла :)

Comment: @CrazyElf Гляньте дополненный ответ :)